# How can I get column name and type from an existing table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2008, orm, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have the table `users` and I want to know what the column names are and what the types are for each column.

I connect like this;

```
connectstring = ('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER%3D%7BSQL'
                     '+Server%7D%3B+server%3D.....')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connectstring).connect()
md = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
table = sqlalchemy.Table('users', md, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
columns = table.c
```

If I call

```
for c in columns:
            print type(columns)
```

I get the output

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.base.ImmutableColumnCollection'>
```

printed once for each column in the table. 
Furthermore,

```
print columns
```

prints

```
['users.column_name_1', 'users.column_name_2', 'users.column_name_3'....]
```

Is it possible to get the column names without the table name being included?

Comment: for c in columns:
            print(type(columns)) will print the type of 'columns', not 'c', for as many times as there are 'c's in 'columns'.

Comment: using this `sqlalchemy.Table(...` method under SQLAlchemy v 1.4 I was getting a 'will be depricated in v 2.0' warning -> by consulting [SQLA meta data docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/metadata.html) I found that removing the `autoload=True` arg clears that warning.  in other words that line in this example would be: `table = sqlalchemy.Table('users', md, autoload_with=engine)`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

columns have `name` and `type` attributes

```
for c in columns:
    print c.name, c.type
```

Comment: If I may add here, you can also get the python type of the column by calling `c.type.python_type`. (See also [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#generic-types))

Answer (score 11):

Better use "inspect" to obtain only information from the columns, with that you do not reflect the table.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import inspect

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(<url>)
insp = inspect(engine)

columns_table = insp.get_columns(<table_name>, <schema>) #schema is optional


for c in columns_table :
    print(c['name'], c['type'])
```

Comment: Approach is encouraging, reflecting from table is more readable. Apart from that, once you have the table object you can write queries as well. Not sure inspections is lazy or not. If it's not lazy you are reading the complete database in one shot.

Answer (score -2):

You could call the column names from the Information Schema:

SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users'

Then sort the result as an array, and loop through them.